# How to Debug Dynamics 365 Business Central ( Wave2 ) in a correct way?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central

I have no idea how to debug Dynamics 365 Business Central ERP Application in an on-premises server.
Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to just link documentation, but the best place to get started is the [MSDN documentation on Business Central debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-debugging). If you're trying to debug an existing session, you'll want to use [Attach and Debug Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/developer/devenv-attach-debug-next).

Both debugging scenarios will require the source code of either the app you're debugging, or the base app that was used to deploy it. Otherwise, view last error (in the help menu) is the only use facing debugging option.

If you have any specific questions, I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is more than enough for me :)